# How do I enter the phone OTP password for login in a website using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I am trying to log in to a website by [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/). For example, log in to the https://pharmeasy.in, but I need to enter the [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) password. Since it is OTP, which is coming in phone. How can I automatically do so like a normal website login?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. By using a virtual phone number from any website provider and fetching an OTP from their website. That's is the easiest possible attempt to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue. After some discussion with my team, it is not possible to handle the OTP with Puppeteer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included more explanation and evidence for this.